# печать текстового поля записи более чем на одной странице

Tags: fastreport

текстовое поле переменного размера, как перенести часть поля на другую страницу, если оно не вошло (не входит на целую страницу) на страницу

Answer (score 0):

У текстового поля ставите `StretchMode = smActualHeight`, у бэнда - `Stretched = True`.
В простом случае, этого достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится, добавьте сначала Band Report Summary, а внутрь секции Memo c параметром stretchmode - maxheight